# Can CMU Sphinx support multiple languages in a sentence?

Tags: cmusphinx

I know CMU Sphinx has many language model , dictionaries and acoustic models.
I want to recognize a sentence which may contain several languages, for example, English and Mandarin.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is better to try more modern framework like Kaldi. And you will have to train models from data, there are no pretrained models.